# Unhandled exception at 0x00898809 in LAB_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCF4. occurred

Tags: c++

When using pointer arrays, I keep getting access violation errors. The code looks right in my eyes, I just might be missing something in terms of initialization. The issue is occuring in the function sort_array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Item {
    int productNum;
    string productName;
    double unitPrice;
    int unitSold;
};

void sort_array(Item* [], int);

int main() {
    ifstream salesFile;
    Item* anItem;
    Item* itemList[100];
    int productNum;
    string productName;
    double unitPrice;
    int unitSold;

    salesFile.open("sales.txt");

    //Store elements of the file into a Item object, store the object in the array.
    int count = 0;
    while (salesFile >> productNum) {
        salesFile >> productName >> unitPrice >> unitSold;

        anItem = new Item;
        (*anItem).productNum = productNum;
        (*anItem).productName = productName;
        (*anItem).unitPrice = unitPrice;
        (*anItem).unitSold = unitSold;

        itemList[count] = anItem;

        count++;
    }
    
    //Sort the array of Item objects by total revenue.
    sort_array(itemList, count);

    //Display the top two best sellers.
    cout << (*itemList[count]).productName << (*itemList[count - 1]).productName;

}

//Function for sorting.
void sort_array(Item* arr[], int n) {
    int f;
    int i;
    for (f = n; f > 0; f--) {
        for (i = 0; i < f; i++) {
            if (arr[i]->unitPrice * arr[i]->unitSold > arr[i + 1]->unitPrice * arr[i + 1]->unitSold) {
                swap(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the first time I've ran into this error, and it seems to be popping up every time I'm trying to assign values to a pointer array.

Comment: `*itemList[count]` in your output statement accesses an uninitialized array member.

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger; they will tell you exactly where this error occurs in your code.

Comment: When you see a highly repetitious number like 0xCCCCCCF4, the program is probably [trying to tell you something.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) In this case it is likely uninitialized stack memory (CCCCCCCC) plus a small offset.

Comment: A debugger will tell you exactly where the program crashes. And in this case that's where the bug is, but often a program will limp on mortally wounded for a while ***after the bug*** and crash somewhere else to sew confusion. In this case it takes a bit more work with the debugger to make it show you where the bug actually is. You have to look for a place in the code where something unexpected happens like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is a bug. Except for when your expectations are wrong. Either way, you need to stop and fix the problem.

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `anItem->productNum` over `(*anItem).productNum`. Most programmers will find the first syntax much easier to read.

Comment: Please add the input file. One error is clear: if `n` is the array size, and initially `f=n`, and `i` can be equal to `f-1`, then you cannot use `arr[i+i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    itemList[count] = anItem;
    count++;
```

So you initialize `itemList[count]` and then increment `count`. So after this, there is no `itemList[count]` since `count` has been incremented.

```
cout << (*itemList[count]).productName << (*itemList[count - 1]).productName;
```

Ooops. You just dereferenced `itemList[count]` which was never initialized.